# Downsample matrix in R?

Tags: r, performance, resampling

My question is about how to improve the performance of function that downsamples from the columns of a matrix without replacement (a.k.a. "rarefication" of a matrix... I know there has been mention of this [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-October/114813.html), but I could not find a clear answer that a) does what I need; b) does it quickly).

Here is my function:

```
downsampled <- function(data,samplerate=0.8) {
    data.test <- apply(data,2,function(q) {
    names(q) <- rownames(data)
    samplepool <- character()
    for (i in names(q)) {
      samplepool <- append(samplepool,rep(i,times=q[i]))  
    }
    sampled <- sample(samplepool,size=samplerate*length(samplepool),replace = F)
    tab <- table(sampled)
    mat <- match(names(tab),names(q))
    toret=numeric(length <- length(q))
    names(toret) <- names(q)
    toret[mat] <- tab
    return(toret)
  })
return(data.test)
}
```

I need to be downsampling matrices with millions of entries.  I find this is quite slow (here I'm using a 1000x1000 matrix, which is about 20-100x smaller than my typical data size):

```
mat <- matrix(sample(0:40,1000*1000,replace=T),ncol=1000,nrow=1000)
colnames(mat) <- paste0("C",1:1000)
rownames(mat) <- paste0("R",1:1000)
system.time(matd <- downsampled(mat,0.8))

##  user  system elapsed 
## 69.322  21.791  92.512
```

Is there a faster/easier way to perform this operation that I haven't thought of?

Comment: In think you want `return(data.test)` in your last-ish line. Also, it's confusing to mix assignment operators (`<-` and `=`). Probably a good idea to stick with one.

Comment: Can you also fix the bugs to make your code reproducible? You say you are making a 1000X1000 matrix, but you actually have 3300 columns and 5000 rows specified, and the code doesn't work because that doesn't match with the lengths of the column and row names. Also, you define the function `downsampled` but then try to call `downsampledata`.

Comment: FYI I made edits to fix the issues in the code highlighted by @lmo and myself

Answer (score 1):

I think you can make this dramatically faster. If I understand what you are trying to do correctly, you want to down-sample each cell of the matrix, such that if `samplerate = 0.5` and the cell of the matrix is `mat[i,j] = 5`, then you want to sample up to 5 things where each thing has a 0.5 chance of being sampled.

To speed things up, rather than doing all these operations on columns of the matrix, you can just loop through each cell of the matrix, draw *n* things from that cell by using `runif` (e.g., if `mat[i,j] = 5`, you can generate 5 random numbers between 0 and 1, and then add up the number of values that are `< samplerate`), and finally add the number of things to a new matrix. I think this effectively achieves the same down-sampling scheme, but much more efficiently (both in terms of running time and lines of code).

```
# Sample matrix
set.seed(23)
n <- 1000
mat <- matrix(sample(0:10,n*n,replace=T),ncol=n,nrow=n)
colnames(mat) <- paste0("C",1:n)
rownames(mat) <- paste0("R",1:n)

# Old function
downsampled<-function(data,samplerate=0.8) {
    data.test<-apply(data,2,function(q){
    names(q)<-rownames(data)
    samplepool<-character()
    for (i in names(q)) {
      samplepool=append(samplepool,rep(i,times=q[i]))  
    }
    sampled=sample(samplepool,size=samplerate*length(samplepool),replace = F)
    tab=table(sampled)
    mat=match(names(tab),names(q))
    toret=numeric(length = length(q))
    names(toret)<-names(q)
    toret[mat]<-tab
    return(toret)
  })
return(data.test)
}

# New function
downsampled2 <- function(mat, samplerate=0.8) {
    new <- matrix(0, nrow(mat), ncol(mat))
    colnames(new) <- colnames(mat)
    rownames(new) <- rownames(mat)
    for (i in 1:nrow(mat)) {
        for (j in 1:ncol(mat)) {
            new[i,j] <- sum(runif(mat[i,j], 0, 1) < samplerate)
        }
    }
    return(new)
}

# Compare times
system.time(downsampled(mat,0.8))
##    user  system elapsed 
##  26.840   3.249  29.902 
system.time(downsampled2(mat,0.8))
##    user  system elapsed 
##   4.704   0.247   4.918
```

Using an example 1000 X 1000 matrix, the new function I provided runs about 6 times faster.

Comment: Thank you so much!  This is exactly the kind of speed-up I was looking for.

And apologies for my code mistakes--I will do better next time!

Comment: glad to help... upvotes for helpful answers are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

One source of savings would be to remove the for loop that appends samplepool using `rep`.  Here is a reproducible example:

```
myRows <- 1:5
names(myRows) <- letters[1:5]
# get the repeated values for sampling
samplepool <- rep(names(myRows), myRows)
```

Within your function, this would be

```
samplepool <- rep(names(q), q)
```